# Retrieving customer data with cfhttp - I/O Exception: peer not authenticated

Tags: coldfusion, http-headers, shopify

I have set up a private app with read access to customer details and customer groups.

My ColdFusion:

```
<cfhttp 
  url="https://[api-key]:[password]@rhein-essentials.myshopify.com/admin/customers.json"
  method="get" result="httpResp" timeout="120">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#httpResp#" />
```

Where [api-key] and [password] were copied from the data that was generated when I created the private app. The response object:

```
struct
Charset         [empty string]
ErrorDetail     I/O Exception: peer not authenticated
Filecontent     Connection Failure
Header          [empty string]
Mimetype        Unable to determine MIME type of file.
Responseheader  struct[empty]
Statuscode      Connection Failure. Status code unavailable.
Text            YES
```

As you can see, it comes back with the error "Connection Failure". The detailed error adds, "I/O Exception: peer not authenticated". At first I was inclined to think this was a problem with my ColdFusion code. But I then tried taking the same url and plugging it directly into my browser. When I'm logged into the Shopify site, the url redirects to https://rhein-essentials.myshopify.com/admin/customers.json and displays the data properly. When I'm logged out, though, the url redirects to https://rhein-essentials.myshopify.com/admin/auth/login. Isn't the point of using the api key and password so that I have access to the data remotely, without needing to be logged in?

**What am I doing wrong, and how can I retrieve data from the store at all without being logged in, if not through ColdFusion?**

Comment: What is the CF version and the Java version it is running on?

Comment: @RRK 9, and 1.8.0_144-b01, respectively.

Comment: Most likely this is a `TLS1.2` issue which is a known issue with CF9. Can you try adding this `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` to the JVM setting in CF administrator?

Comment: Another thing to check is that you have the site's public TLS certificate within the Java keystore that ColdFusion is using on your server. Or it's trusted certificate authority.

Comment: I think the certificate is not installed in coldfusion's certificate truststore. See https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? Just curious.

Comment: @RRK I've talked with the SA and we've decided to update the version of CF completely. I'll post an answer if it works, although it would be a rather roundabout solution. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RRK pointed out,

> Most likely this is a TLS1.2 issue which is a known issue with CF9. Can you try adding this `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` to the JVM setting in CF administrator?

It would seem that it was indeed a CF9 issue, because after upgrading it to CF 2016 Patch 6, along with Java 8 x64 V 172, it retrieved the data fine.

Comment: Glad it's resolved and thanks for posting the resolution. Though if @RRK's comment was the answer, or helped lead to it, feel to ask them to promote their comment to an answer next time.  Just as a thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Ageax RRK is welcome to promote their comment, since I feel that it's a different solution than the one I used. Since it wasn't exactly the solution I used, however, I'm just going off what I read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question). IMO, RRK should have posted it as an answer in the first place.

Comment: @SypderScript - Yeah, that's a tricky one. Sometimes people do it deliberately and other times because they're waiting on feedback/confirmation that it solved the problem. That said, I agree the overall solution was different so it still warrants a separate answer either way.